Meaning of Parāśara smṛti (11.40)- Devatās in pañcagavya
I wish to know the meaning of Parāśara smṛti (11.40) - 

varuṇaścaiva gomūtre gomaye havyavāhanaḥ / 
dadhni vāyuḥ samuddiṣṭaḥ somaḥ kṣīre ghṛte raviḥ //

Are there any commentaries (comms.) which specify what this smṛtivākya implies?

Parāśara smṛti (11.28) explains what is pañcagavya-

gomūtraṁ gomayaṁ kṣīraṁ dadhi sarpi kuśodakam / 
nirddiṣṭaṁ pañcagavyaṁ tu pavitraṁ pāpaśodhanaṁ // 

This vākya states that pañcagavya comprises of gomūtra, gomaya, kṣīram, dadhi, and sarpi (ghṛta), dissolved with kuśa jala.  This pañcagavya is pavitra and pāpaśodhaka.
Parāśara smṛti (11.40) states the adhiṣṭhita devatās in the five dravyas in pañcagavya -

varuṇaścaiva gomūtre gomaye havyavāhanaḥ / 
dadhni vāyuḥ samuddiṣṭaḥ somaḥ kṣīre ghṛte raviḥ //

Varuṇa is adhiṣṭhita in gomūtra, Havyavāhana (Agni) is adhiṣṭhia in gomaya, Vāyu is adhiṣthita in dadhi, Soma (Candra) is adhiṣṭhita in kṣīra, and Ravi (Sūrya) is adhiṣṭhita in ghṛta.
In his comm., Mādhavācārya states that it's due to Varuṇa, etc. devatās being adhiṣṭhita in pañcagavya, that it's upapanna (endowed) with pāpadāhakatvam (as per Parāśara smṛti 11.28).

iti / varuṇādibhiradhiṣṭhitatvāt pāpadāhakatvamupapannam //

Thus, the meaning of Parāśara smṛti (11.40) has been explained with Mādhavācārya's comm.
